# Comparing strings and getting the most frequent serie of letters

Tags: python, list

I am having multiple list of words such as:

```
a = ['java','java 2','javascript','java']
b = ['finds','finding','afinder what','find']
```

And I want to kind 'name' each list. Until now I was using the following function that I made which was taking the most frequent word of the list:

```
def findMostFrequentWord(alist):
    listOfWords = ' '.join(alist).split(' ')
    mostFrequent = max(listOfWords,key=listOfWords.count)
    return mostFrequent

findMostFrequentWord(a)
'java'
findMostFrequentWord(b)
'finds'
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to have as output the highest rate of a sequence of letters. For example the list `b` should give as output the word `find` as the sequence of the letters `f`,`i`,`n`,`d` is the most frequent in the different values. I cant think of a methodology to check that and also seems to be kinda expensive from a computational perspective. Any comments?

Comment: So to be clear, you search the longest string in the set of the most common substrings?

Comment: @timgeb Initially my thought was 'the most common set of letters between different strings' , but by your question I realized that the probably the result is a single letter. So something like ' the most common set of letters between different strings with a threshold in the length of the sequence'. Probably there is a better way to 'name' a list of values but this is what it came to my mind. If you think that something else could work better just recommend it :)